# Element ordering effect on floating in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, web, css-float

I have this simple HTML:

```html
<body>          
    <div class="square" id="black"></div>
    <div class="square" id="yellow"></div>           
</body>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
.square {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;    
}

#black {
    background-color: black;            
    float:left;   
}

#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;          
}
```

From what I've learned, when an element is floated it's taken out of the page flow. It's as if float and non-float elements ignores each other. So the black square just sits on top the yellow and hides it:

[image]

But when floating the yellow square instead:

```css
#black {
    background-color: black;                      
}

#yellow {
    background-color: yellow; 
    float:left;          
}
```

We get :

[image]

I am trying to figure out the logic behind this.
How **element ordering** in the html and **floating mechanics** play together ? Who wins when ?

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C Float Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) actually does a pretty good job of answering this question.

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line...   Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist.

This explains why the float covers the yellow box in the first example.

As for the second example, `#black` *is* in the content flow and is `display: block` and thus has its own line.  `#yellow` in that case is on a different line.

Comment: So regarding this quote from W3C, why does the yellow box does not cover the black like in the first example ?

Comment: @YaronLevi the yellow box is on the next line because the black box is `display: block`